# Why does this example on sorting doesn't work in python?

Tags: python, list, sorting

```
>>> a = ['7','30','41','14','39','42']
>>> a.sort()
>>> a
['14', '30', '39', '41', '42', '7']
```

was not it supposed to print the following??

```
>>> a
['7', '14', '30', '39', '41', '42']
```

Comment: They're sorted as a string rather than as numbers; removing the quotes should cause them to be sorted as you'd expect; i.e. `a = [7,30,41,14,39,42]`

Comment: You're sorting _strings_, not numbers. They sort by alphabetical order. If you want to sort by numerical value, you can either use a list of numbers in the first place, or use a sort key, like `a.sort(key=int)`.

Comment: If you need more information, the duplicate questions have great answers, and the [Sorting HOWTO](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html) in the docs has further details.

Comment: If you want to sort numbers, you have to cast string to integers. a.sort(key=int)